# How to post request login to get into dashboard . and save the token in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a task to post request to api , basicly i always use json fake server to get username and password. but for this task i have to post request login with axios post. and headers application/json and body username,password. and define client id in body so, we just type username and password in form login but client id already define in body . and the problem i already try to post request but always getting error, and i wonder how to save the q / token before i get into dashboard. thank you

login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

      let isLogedIn = true
      if (token === null) {
          isLogedIn = false
      }

      this.state = {
          post : [],
          isLogedIn,
          id : '',
          username : '',
          password: '', 
      }

      this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
      this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleForm  = (e) => { 
      this.setState ({
         [e.target.name] : e.target.value
      })
    }

handleSubmit  () {

      const data = JSON.stringify({
        clientId : "authService",  
        clientSecret : "123",
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password 
      })

      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }

      axios.post('http://10.50.51.21:8062/token', data, {
            headers: headers

        }
      )


      .then ((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token","this is token that i save before i get into dashboard")
        console.log(response)
        this.setState ({
          isLogedIn : true
        })
      })

      .catch (err => {
        console.log("Error : " ,err )
      })
      console.log(data);
    }
```

thankyou, please tell me what should i do. thank you very much to helping me

Comment: after successful login right after use this.props.history.push('/dashboard') . and before that save token in localstorage.

Comment: yeah, i know but how to save token ? , i use post request, and the response from server like

"responseCode": "00",     "message": "Process successful. ",     "localMessage": "Proses Success.",     "response": {         
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzcyI6Im9tbmktY2hhbm5lb CIsImV4cCI6MTU0NzExMDI2MCwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsImlhdCI6MTU ",
 "refresh": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzcyI6Im9tbmktY2hhbm5lb CIsImV4cCI6MTU0NzExMDI2MCwidHlwZSI6InJlZnJlc2giLCJpYXQiOjE1 NDcxMDg0NjAsIn",
 "tokenType": "bearer",         "expiredAt": 1547110260     } }

Comment: how to save token from response server ?

Comment: example : `localStorage.set('token', response.token)`

Comment: already tried, undefined. that api is from server, so the client request token by validate username,password,client id .

Comment: undefined when set token

Comment: @Alexsandro Siregar try this localStorage.setItem('token', response.token)

Comment: still undefined...

Comment: i succes get the token, and now . he problem sometimes i login sometimes not .

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
axios.post('http://10.50.51.21:8062/token', data, {
            headers: headers
        }
      ).then(response=>response.json()
      ).then(response =>{
            localStorage.setItem("token",response.token)
            console.log(response)
            this.setState ({
                isLogedIn : true
            })

      })
```

Comment: yeah i already get the token bro, the problem how to verifi if the username and password from handle submit is true

Comment: the setstate in .then uselsss. i already set state isLogein true but keep not login. and the token is null. but when i console log.  the token is not null